# Linux driver for ASUS Shock Shied hard drive active protection

Tags: drivers, hard-disk, hardware, laptop, asus

Does there exist a Linux driver for ASUS laptop Shock Shied hard drive active protection mechanism (based on a 3D digital accelerometer sensor)?

I could only find [`hdapsd`](https://github.com/evgeni/hdapsd/) which does not list ASUS as supported.

Answer (score 0):

ASUS HDD Shock Shied doesn't need OS support to operate. This is the disk controller firmware that reads the sensor and stops the disk to prevent it from being damaged.

Comment: Great if true! Is there any way to monitor its operation under Linux?

Comment: If i cannot test its operation, could you, please, give me some link or other details confirming your words?